# Encoding and decoding issue during inserting into mysql database using perl

Tags: perl

I need help for this. Am taking attached screenshot mention description from one which character set is UTF-8.

[image: "description"]

---

Am decoding the values by HTML::Entities after that my result is like below.

> Rémunération De 9.61 à 10.45 € Secteur Contrat IntÃ©rim Niveau d''Ã©tudes BAC+2/3 ExpÃ©rience requise 3 annÃ©es Votre agence NANCY Le CarrÃ© Rive Gauche - entrÃ©e 3

I need to insert the recored into mysql table like this; My table column is in utf8_general_ci and default character set is UTF-8 please help me from this.

> Rémunération De 9.61 à 10.45 € Secteur Contrat Intérim Niveau d''études BAC+2/3 Expérience requise 3 années Votre agence NANCY Le Carré Rive Gauche - entrée 3

Comment: I'm confused. Why do you have `é` in some places in your original string (e.g. `Rémunération`), but `Ã©` in others (e.g. `ExpÃ©rience`)? Where is your original string coming from, and why are some `é`s encoded properly but some aren't?

Comment: I know it does not provide an answer, but @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, I had the same problem with a CSV file I got from the chamber of commerce, the categories had 'café' and there were names in the files, also including the 'é' - however the names were converted properly, but the categories made my database populate script even crash - had to 'manually' change the names of the categories in the cvs file before i got it working... different encodings in the same file? never really figured out what went wrong, had to get things done!

Comment: The string is from website.

Comment: @Sownder And how do you get the string? Are you copy-and-pasting it out of a browser? Are you scraping the site with `LWP::UserAgent`, `WWW::Mechanize`, or similar? Are you downloading it with `curl` or `wget`? Something completely different? In other words, is the website itself improperly encoded, or are you doing something to it when you fetch the content?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot am using LWP::UserAgent to fetch data from website and encoding those using HTML::Entities and inserting using DBI.

Comment: Okay...and that screenshot is of the raw HTML source, before you download it and try to process it? (i.e. what you see if you right-click the page in your browser and select "View Page Source")

Comment: From the page source only i got this content.